# Check if a ptr belongs to a virtual class?

Tags: c++, casting

My code was acting wonky and i was able to mini reproduce it with the code below. ([codepad link](http://codepad.org/dnurtsaM))

From http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/dynamic_cast

> If you attempt to cast to a pointer
>   type, and that type is not an actual
>   type of the argument object, then the
>   result of the cast will be NULL.

From my understanding this_test should be null. It isnt. How do i check if that dummy ptr is actually a ptr to a dummy object?

```
#include <ios>
struct Dummy{ virtual void dummyfn(){} };

int main(){
Dummy* this_test = dynamic_cast<Dummy*>((Dummy*)0x123);
//assert(this_test==0);
cout << std::hex << this_test<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x123
```

Comment: A Dummey* is already a Dummy* so the cast could be optimized away. The dynamic_cast assumes you are not lying about the input type (which is what C-Casts are. Lies to the compiler (Its a Dummy pointer; onestly guv you got-ta believe me)).

Comment: @Martin: Do you know of a way to force checking? void* doesnt work

Comment: Why do you have to check! You already know that 0x123 isn't a pointer.

Comment: Rather than tell us what you are doing. Try telling us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `dynamic_cast` expects either:

- a null pointer
- a *valid* pointer

Here you can only offer it garbage, so it is useless, and not the cast you want.

If you are getting a `void*`, then you can use `reinterpret_cast` (better than a C-cast, because more visible) to cast it into another type:

```
void* p = 0x123;
Dummy* dummy = reinterpret_cast<Dummy*>(p);
```

*Note: the presence or absence of virtual methods goes unnoticed here*

---

**EDIT**: if you can modify the objects being passed...

Then try to use a common base class:

```
struct Base: private boost::noncopyable { virtual ~Base() = 0 }; Base::~Base() {}
```

And define the following helpers:

```
template <typename T>
void* to_void(T* t) {
  Base* base = t;
  return reinterpret_cast<void*>(base);
}

template <typename T>
T* from_void(void* p) {
  Base* base = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(p);
  return dynamic_cast<T*>(base);
}
```

The former is extremely important because of the possible pointer adjustment (which will probably only occur in the case of Multiple Inheritance).

*Note: it's possible to use a `fast_cast` here if you don't use virtual inheritance or other RTTI stuff*

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T* fast_cast(U* u) {
#ifdef NDEBUG
  return static_cast<T*>(u);
#else
  return dynamic_cast<T*>(u);
#endif
}
```

---

If this is not possible the following solutions are possible, but they are going to feel hacky I fear.

Since `dynamic_cast` is not going to work properly here, you have to actually come up with your own type checking mechanism.

One method could be to use a "repository" in which you register the `void*` pointers you get, and the associated `type_info` object.

```
typedef std::map<void*, std::type_info const*> Repository;

template <typename Dest>
Dest* dynamic_check(void* p, Repository const& rep) {
  Repository::const_iterator it = rep.find(p);
  assert(it != rep.end() && "dynamic_check: no such entry");

  assert(typeid(Dest) == *(it->second) && "dynamic_check: wrong type");

  return reinterpret_cast<Dest*>(p);
}
```

If this is not possible, then you could hack the C++ object model to your advantage. If you know that the object has at least one virtual method, then it necessarily has a virtual pointer on all compilers I know (VS, gcc, clang), and this pointer is the first 4/8 bytes of the object.

```
inline void* virtual_pointer(void* p) {
  assert(p != 0 && "virtual_pointer: null");
  return reinterpret_cast<void*>(*p);
}

template <typename T>
void* virtual_pointer(T const& t) {
  return virtual_pointer(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&t));
}

template <typename T>
void* virtual_pointer() {
  static void* pointer = virtual_pointer(T());
  return pointer;
}


template <typename Dest>
Dest* dynamic_check(void* p) {
  assert(virtual_pointer<Dest>() == virtual_pointer(p));
  return reinterpret_cast<Dest*>(p);
}
```

**Note**: both solutions suffer from the same shortcoming, they will only work if you precise the *exact* type (well, you could get away with it as long as two types share the same virtual table, which happens if a derived class does not override any virtual method, including the destructor).

This is far from the power of a true `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: I love this answer. If i get some kind of problem making everything use the same base class (perhaps related to the diamond problem) i will be doing this

Comment: @acidzombie24: if you can make everything use the same base class **and** don't forget to cast to that class before transforming into a `void*` (because of pointer arithmetic), then don't use this ;) In fact, I'll edit my answer to incorporate this alternative, I just thought (why ?) that you could not alter the objects being passed in...

Comment: cool. wait... i need to remember to cast before transforming into void!!! that is way to much work. Actually, this doesnt make any sense. If all classes use that class as a base class and there are no diamond problems then the base class should be topmost/first. So shouldn't this work fine without? i could generate a test for each class that checks if the ptr before and after casting to base is the same but i dont think this will be a problem?

Comment: Alright so i looked at your comment before your code and you seem to agree it only would be a problem for multiple inheritance (which i actually do but B is ALWAYS first). IIRC i couldnt use static_cast everywhere i could use dynamic_cast. Maybe i am remembering wrong. For your main change, you use boost::noncopyable  and to_void function. Why not just have a `operator void*()` instead and not use noncopyable. No code would need to change and it feels natural. (unless you could find a problem.)

Comment: @acidzombie24: `noncopyable` is an habit of mine for interfaces. Copying polymorphic classes is usually erroneous (slicing issue) unless you happen to know that you are dealing with the most derived class. You could also make the copy constructor and assignment operator protected instead. Regarding the casting issue, it should be fine if you avoid multi-inheritance, and will be fine if you integrate the check to your unit-tests :) I personally don't appreciate implicit casts, because they have the tendency to be triggered where they don't make sense. For example, `if (derived)` would be true..

Comment: .. because it would implicitly cast to a non-null `void*`, even though the semantic is certainly not what you wanted. Finally, regarding `static_cast` vs `dynamic_cast`: the dynamic cast allows you to check whether it is a certain type or not dynamically, while the static cast assumes you know what you are casting into. They are certainly not interchangeable, I just had the impression that in your case you knew perfectly what you wanted to cast into, if it is not the case, then use `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Wishful thinking... :)

I believe `dynamic_cast` only works for downcasts in polymorphic cases, not *any* cast whatsoever. It's not like the compiler stores type information for every single variable, so it can't do what you're thinking -- I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior.

Comment: From what i remember it uses virtual tables to deduce the type. Also rtti is enabled

Comment: @acidzombie24: RTTI is a bit different than what's happening here, and no, the fact that you have a virtual method doesn't mean anything because there's no virtual table at the address `0x123` for the compiler to look at in the first place, and it's *certainly* not down the same hierarchy. Lying to the compiler is ~dangerous~.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thats actually why i need this. i only have void* coming in and HUNDREDS of them. Its using c weak typing. I need a way to check if the type is what i am expecting it to be so it doesnt explode on me. -edit- maybe thousands of void * in this project.

Comment: @acidzombie24: It only uses C weak typing? C has virtual functions and RTTI?

Comment: @Mehrdad: some interfaces are expressed in term of `void*` when you use them with C++ code you can actually pass pointers to C++ objects as long as they are not manipulated by the C in-between, but merely passed as is.

Comment: @Matthieu: Are you talking about COM? COM is obviously separate from the C and C++ standards, so there's naturally no standard mechanism for detecting the type of pointers. If you know it's an `IUnknown*`, then cast it to that and use `QueryInterface` to get more info, but if this is about some other mechanism, there's just no way to do this in C++ -- AFAIK, C++ has no defined ABI.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: thats exactly whats happening here. @Meh the code is in C, quiet large and it only passes void*. It would be nice if it was in C++ and has templates but this code was started like 30yrs ago and is considered a good library. Now i am using C++ to help me write nice and correct code

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have never used COM, but I have used a number of C libraries and `void*` is often used. I believe there are ways to do *some* type checking, the lack of ABI is annoying but there are some constants one can exploit as long as one knows on which compilers/platforms the code is expected to run. It's hackish, but when you're stuck...

Answer (score 1):

You skipped one sentence from your quote:

> The `dynamic_cast` keyword casts `object` from one pointer or reference type to another, performing a runtime check to ensure the validity of the cast.

The problem here is that 0x123 isn't a pointer to an object, so it just doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying i should test with an int ptr? cause that doesnt work http://codepad.org/xAoLlR4y (i am tempted to -1)

Comment: @acidzombie24 - You could, and the compiler would turn than into always returning a null pointer, because an int* can't legally point to a Dummy either. To be useful, the pointer should be a pointer to a base class of Dummy (if it had any).

Comment: @acidzombie24 - Checked you link. The problem is your C style cast. Using a `(Dummy *)` you tell the compiler that you know **for sure** that the pointer is of that type. And it has to believe you!

Comment: well thats my problem. The c code (lib, not mine) passes a lot of pointers around and its easy to get them mixed up or except something wrong. My function THINKS its a Dummy but it could be something else

Comment: That is a big problem. If the type info is lost, it **is** lost. Sorry!

Comment: I'm very happy most of the classes/structs are generated. What i did was stick B in front of everything then write `dynamic_cast<ExpectingType*>((B*)expectingType)` and it caught the bug i initially found. It looks like its working the way i hoped now. +1 and accepted

Comment: Honorable mention this answer. If i couldnt make everything take a base class then i would need to do this which looks like a well done alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503714/check-if-a-ptr-belongs-to-a-virtual-class/5504287#5504287

Answer (score 0):

Actually `dynamic_cast` only works on polymorphic types (usually this means they must have a vtable). Since you're using a C-cast to assert to the compiler that the type is `Dummy*`, it believes you. Since you're then doing an identity `dynamic_cast` on a random memory location it doesn't/isn't able to do the type checking.

But seriously, 99% of the time don't try to test that something is a particular type. Design your classes such that the base classes define an interface and the child classes implement it, allowing use without lots of casting (which is a design smell).

Comment: Problem is i am using C code that loses ALL TYPES and all i get are ints and void*. So i need to make sure all my functions and params are the type i expect. Much of the code is generated but right now i hit a bug and it turns out one param is not the type i expect. But i am also not getting a null ptr so my asserts arent being set off. Thus its a lot harder to track (lucky vc is exploding at all the right spots)

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` does not perform any run-time checking when you use it for upcasts or identity-casts (casts to the same type). For such casts `dynamic_cast` behaves exactly the same as an ordinary `static_cast`. No difference whatsoever.

The page you linked does not mention that, i.e. is not even a remotely complete specification of `dynamic_cast`, which makes it pretty useless.

C++ provides no means to determine whether a given pointer is actually a valid pointer to a given type. So, you are out of luck there. Implement your own checking method.